# Keep dynamic changes when saving webpage in ie11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-11

I need to save a webpage to the filesystem using the Save Webpage function while keeping changes done with javascript. I have an input field where you can type in your name and save it, which is then displayed on the website. If i use Save As... in firefox my changes are saved in the resulting html file. When i use IE11 i get the original source code without my user input.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script>
        function saveUser(form) {
            var form = document.getElementById('saveUserForm');
            form.previousElementSibling.innerHTML = form.previousElementSibling.innerHTML + "<br />Created by: " + form.name.value;
            form.parentNode.removeChild(form);
        }
    </script>  
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Test Page</h1>
        <p>Created at: Today
            <form class="userForm" id="saveUserForm" action="" method="get">
                <label for="name">Created by:&nbsp;</label>
                <input id="name" name="name">
                <input type="button" name="button" value="Save" onclick="saveUser(this.form)" />
            </form>
        </p>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Can anybody make any suggestions on how to keep dynamic changes when saving a web page in IE11?